# Extracting a string between other two strings in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am trying to find a simple way to extract an unknown substring (could be anything) that appear between two known substrings. For example, I have a string:

`a<-" anything goes here, STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here"`

I need to extract the string `GET_ME` which is between STR1 and STR2 (without the white spaces).

I am trying `str_extract(a, "STR1 (.+) STR2")`, but I am getting the entire match

```
[1] "STR1 GET_ME STR2"
```

I can of course strip the known strings, to isolate the substring I need, but I think there should be a cleaner way to do it by using a correct regular expression.

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321) fantastic function `regcapturedmatches(test, gregexpr('STR1 (.+?) STR2', test, perl = TRUE))`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You may use `str_match` with `STR1 (.*?) STR2` (note the spaces are "meaningful", if you want to just match anything in between `STR1` and `STR2` use `STR1(.*?)STR2`, or use `STR1\\s*(.*?)\\s*STR2` to trim the value you need). If you have multiple occurrences, use `str_match_all`.

Also, if you need to match strings that span across line breaks/newlines add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern: `(?s)STR1(.*?)STR2` / `(?s)STR1\\s*(.*?)\\s*STR2`.

```
library(stringr)
a <- " anything goes here, STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here"
res <- str_match(a, "STR1\\s*(.*?)\\s*STR2")
res[,2]
[1] "GET_ME"
```

Another way using base R `regexec` (to get the first match):

```
test <- " anything goes here, STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here STR1 GET_ME2 STR2"
pattern <- "STR1\\s*(.*?)\\s*STR2"
result <- regmatches(test, regexec(pattern, test))
result[[1]][2]
[1] "GET_ME"
```

Comment: It works! What is the purpose of the question mark? It seems to work without it as well.

Comment: The `?` here is a part of a *lazy* (non-greedy) quantifier. It matches as few characters as possible, while `*` will match as many as possible. So, `STR1 .*? STR2` regex matches `STR1 xx STR2`, and `STR1 .* STR2` will match `STR1 xx STR2 zzz STR2`. If you expect multiple matches in your input, lazy quantifier is a must here. Also, FYI: if the part of string between `STR1` and `STR2` may contain newlines, you need to prepend the pattern with `(?s)`: `"(?s)STR1 (.*?) STR2"`.

Comment: @Wiktor: Can you explain why on earth `str_match` output is in a matrix? It seems so inconvenient, particularly when the only output most people ever want is `[,2]`

Comment: @Nettle I would disagree because if anyone only wants `[,2]`, they should use a mere `regmatches(a, regexpr("STR1\\s*\\K.*?(?=\\s*STR2)", a, perl=TRUE))`. With `stringr`, it is also possible to use a pattern like `str_extract_all(a, "(?s)(?<=STR1\\s{0,1000}).*?(?=\\s*STR2)")
` (though for some reason the space is still included in the match, and it is rather hacky). `str_match` is a life savior when you need to return all matches and captures. Also, the pattern that can be used with `str_match` is much more efficient.

Comment: @Wiktor: `regmatches/regexpr` combo chokes on an expression that's fine in stringr...so your expression `str_extract_all(a, "(?s)(?<=STR1\\s{0,1000}).*?(?=\\s*STR2)")` can't be applied as `regmatches(a,regexpr("(?s)(?<=STR1\\s{0,1000}).*?(?=\\s*STR2)", a, perl = TRUE) ) ` Why is that?

Comment: @Nettle *stringr* regex is based on ICU library, the lookbehind patterns may contain limiting quantifiers (like `{0,10}`), and this is not allowed in PCRE patterns (base R `(g)sub` / `(g)regexpr`  with `perl=TRUE`).

Comment: I have written a general [article about extracting strings between two strings with regex](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/extracting-text-two-strings-regular-expressions), too, feel free to read if you have a problem approaching your current similar problem.

Answer (score 61):

Here's another way by using base R

```
a<-" anything goes here, STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here"

gsub(".*STR1 (.+) STR2.*", "\\1", a)
```

Output:

```
[1] "GET_ME"
```

Comment: Can you explain the `\\1`?

Comment: @GiovanniColitti `( )` components in the pattern are automatically numbered, so `\\1` is telling R to return the first `( )` component (which there is only one of). See what happens when you wrap `STR1` and `STR2` in parentheses and try `\\1`, `\\2`, and `\\3`: `gsub(".*(STR1) (.+) (STR2).*", "\\2", a)`

Comment: For my particular case, I had to replace `(.+)` with `*(.*?)`

Answer (score 20):

Another option is to use `qdapRegex::ex_between` to extract strings between left and right boundaries

```
qdapRegex::ex_between(a, "STR1", "STR2")[[1]]
#[1] "GET_ME"
```

It also works with multiple occurrences

```
a <- "anything STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here, STR1 again get me STR2"

qdapRegex::ex_between(a, "STR1", "STR2")[[1]]
#[1] "GET_ME"       "again get me"
```

Or multiple left and right boundaries

```
a <- "anything STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here, STR4 again get me STR5"
qdapRegex::ex_between(a, c("STR1", "STR4"), c("STR2", "STR5"))[[1]]
#[1] "GET_ME"       "again get me"
```

First capture is between "STR1" and "STR2" whereas second between "STR4" and "STR5".

Answer (score 3):

We could use *{unglue}*, in that case we don't need regex at all :

```
library(unglue)
unglue::unglue_vec(
  " anything goes here, STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here", 
  "{}STR1 {x} STR2{}")
#> [1] "GET_ME"
```

`{}` matches anything without keeping it, `{x}` captures its match (any variable other than `x` could be used. The syntax`"{}STR1 {x} STR2{}"`  is short for : `"{=.*?}STR1 {x=.*?} STR2{=.*?}"`

If you wanted to extract the sides too you could do:

```
unglue::unglue_data(
  " anything goes here, STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here", 
  "{left}, STR1 {x} STR2, {right}")
#>                  left      x              right
#> 1  anything goes here GET_ME anything goes here
```

Comment: If we want to use any variable instead of STR1 and STR2,how can we. Let's say I assign STR1 to a and STR2 to b, now how can we use regex to extract string between a and b

Comment: Instead of `"{left}, STR1 {x} STR2, {right}"` you could use `sprintf("{left}, %s {x} %s, {right}", a, b)`, or `paste0("{left}, ", a, " {x} ", b, ", {right}")`