# How to export marked text in R?

Tags: r, text

Imagine you have text variable like:

```
x = as.character("If you do not 'answer' this question, 'two' persons will 'die' in the next second")
```

What is the best function to return only the quotation marked words such that

```
> FUNCTION(x)
> [1] "answer" "two"    "die"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting a string between other two strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086400/extracting-a-string-between-other-two-strings-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stringr` package...

```
library(stringr)
y <- str_match_all(x,"\\'([^\\s]+)\\'")[[1]][,2]

y
[1] "answer" "two"    "die"
```

If you are applying it to a vector `x`, `str_match_all` will produce a list with a 2-column matrix for each element of `x`.  You need the second column of each.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using base package:

```
x = "If you do not 'answer' this question, 'two' persons will 'die' in the next second"

gsub( "'",
      "",
      grep(
        pattern = "'[a-z]+'",
        x = strsplit(x, " ")[[1]],
        value   = T 
        )
     )

# [1] "answer" "two"    "die"
```