# Extract all strings between two other strings?

Tags: r, stringr

Question is exactly the same as [how to extract a string from between two other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086400/extracting-a-string-between-other-two-strings-in-r), except for extracting ***all*** strings between the two other strings.

To use the a similar example as the original question, suppose we wish to extract `GET_ME` and `GET_ME_TOO` from the string

```
a <-" anything goes here, STR1 GET_ME STR2, anything goes here STR1 GET_ME_TOO STR2"
res <- str_match(a, "STR1 (.*?) STR2")
res[,2]
[1] "GET_ME"
```

This retrieves the first, but not second (or subsequent) occurrences

#### Question

How can we extract ***all*** strings between two other strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_match_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(a, "STR1 (.*?) STR2")
#[[1]]
#     [,1]                   [,2]        
#[1,] "STR1 GET_ME STR2"     "GET_ME"    
#[2,] "STR1 GET_ME_TOO STR2" "GET_ME_TOO"
```