# Regex lookback problem, need quick advice

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping

I'm trying to solve this regex problem:

**String:**

> "notme notme <P abc>getme1</P> notme notme <P dfg>getme2</P> notme
> notme"

**Want this:**

> "getme1 getme2"

**This regex solves it if the <P> does not contain more text**

> "(?<=<P>)(.|\n)*?(?=</P>)"

**If I write it like this, I get an error in the lookback:**

> "(?<=<P.*?>)(.|\n)*?(?=</P>)"

Appreciate every contribution!

Best regards
M

Comment: Makes me wonder if it would be easier to parse data with `rvest` package.

Comment: `regmatches( x, gregexpr("(?<=\\<P [a-z]{3}\\>).+?(?=\\<)", x, perl = TRUE ) )`

Comment: Unfortunately, rvest is not an option because of some namespace error in some tags.

Comment: First of all, do not use `(.|\n)*?` like regex patterns, EVER, see [this YT video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEobSs-ZCSE). Next, there are several solutions, but the most straight-forward is `stringr::str_match_all(x, "(?s)<P[^>]*>(.*?)</P>")`. Base R: `regmatches(x, gregexpr("(?s)<P[^>]*>\\K.*?(?=</P>)", x, perl=TRUE))`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086448/3832970).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Wiktor. It seems like your solution includes the tags(I want them removed). Do have a solution for that?