# Search for matches to argument pattern within every item of a character vector and a window function

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have the following string

```
library(stringi)
s=stri_rand_lipsum(10)
```

Function `grepl` searches for matches to argument pattern within every item of a character vector. As far as I know, it performs the search of just one word at once. For example if I would like to search "conubia" and "viverra" I have to perform two searches:

```
x=s[grepl("conubia",s)]
x=x[grepl("viverra",x)]
```

Anyway, I would like to search two or more terms which appear in the same entry of `s` within a window of length equal to, e.g. 140 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*apply` family. If your source text is a character vector, I recommend using `vapply`, but you have to specify the type and the length of the returned values. Because you use `grepl`, the returned values are logical vectors.

```
txt = "My name is Abdur Rohman"
patt = c("na", "Ab","man", "om")

vapply(patt, function(x) grepl(x,txt), 
       FUN.VALUE = logical(length(txt)))
# na    Ab   man    om 
# TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

So, in your example you can use:

```
s = stri_rand_lipsum(10)
vapply(c("conubia","viverra"), function(x) grepl(x,s), 
       FUN.VALUE = logical(length(s))
#      conubia viverra
# [1,]    TRUE    TRUE
# [2,]   FALSE   FALSE
# [3,]    TRUE   FALSE
# [4,]   FALSE   FALSE
# [5,]   FALSE   FALSE
# [6,]   FALSE    TRUE
# [7,]   FALSE   FALSE
# [8,]   FALSE   FALSE
# [9,]   FALSE   FALSE
#[10,]   FALSE   FALSE
```

**Edit to include a 140-character window**

As for the requirement to create a limiting window with 140-character length, as explained in your comment, one way of meeting the requirement is by extracting all characters between the two targeted strings, and then calculate the number of the extracted characters. The requirement is met only if the number is less than or equal to 140.

Extracting all characters between two strings can be done by regular expressions in `gsub`. However,in case the strings are repeated,  you need to specify the window. Let me give examples:

```
txt <- "Lorem conubia amet conubia ipsum dolor sit amet, finibus torquent diam lobortis dolor ac eget viverra dolor viverra"
```

This text contains two `conubia`s and two `viverra`s. You have four options to choose the window to specify `all characters between conubia and viverra`.

1. Option 1: between the last `conubia` and the first `viverra`

```
gsub(".*conubia(.*?)viverra.*", "\\1", txt, perl = TRUE)
#[1] " ipsum dolor sit amet, finibus torquent diam lobortis dolor ac eget "
```

2. Option 2: between the first `conubia` and the last `viverra`

```
gsub(".*?conubia(.*)viverra.*", "\\1", txt, perl = TRUE)
# [1] " amet conubia ipsum dolor sit amet, finibus torquent diam lobortis dolor ac eget viverra dolor "
```

3. Option 3: between the first `conubia` and the first `viverra`

```
gsub(".*?conubia(.*?)viverra.*", "\\1", txt, perl = TRUE)
#[1] " amet conubia ipsum dolor sit amet, finibus torquent diam lobortis dolor ac eget "
```

4. Option 4: between the last `conubia` and the last `viverra`

```
gsub(".*conubia(.*)viverra.*", "\\1", txt, perl = TRUE)
#[1] " ipsum dolor sit amet, finibus torquent diam lobortis dolor ac eget viverra dolor "
```

To calculate the number of the extracted characters, `nchar` can be used.

```
# Option 1
nchar(gsub(".*conubia(.*?)viverra.*", "\\1", txt, perl = TRUE))
#[1] 68
```

Applying this approach:

```
set.seed(8)
s1 <- stri_rand_lipsum(10)
Nch <- nchar(gsub(".*conubia(.*?)viverra.*", "\\1", s1, perl = TRUE))
Nch
# [1] 637  42 512 528 595 640 522 407 388 512
```

we found that the second element of `s1` meets the requirement.
To print the element we can use: `s1[which(Nch <= 140)]`.

Some great references I've been learning from:

1. https://www.buymeacoffee.com/wstribizew/extracting-text-two-strings-regular-expressions
2. https://regex101.com/
3. [Extracting a string between other two strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086400/extracting-a-string-between-other-two-strings-in-r)

Comment: Thank you Abdur! But I can't find the control on window  length of 140 characters.

Comment: Sorry,  I missed this requirement. Do you mean that the two or more terms, such as "conubia" and "viverra" are all located inside a string of which the length does not exceed 140 characters? Please correct me if I misunderstand your requirement.

Comment: No, I mean that, if "conubia" and "viverra" are separated by more than 140 characters in the same string, then they should not be considered