# Extract string from JSON parsed character vector

Tags: r, json, string

Could anyone please help me and explain how can I extract a string from a character vector that contains special characters in it?

I'm working with a vector like this:

```
txt <- c("{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}", "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", 
"{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", 
"{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}", "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", 
"{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", "{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}", 
"{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}"
)

> txt
 [1] "{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}"       "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}"
 [3] "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}" "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}"
 [5] "{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}"       "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}"
 [7] "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}" "{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}"      
 [9] "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}" "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}"
```

I'd like to extract only the `Describes me best` and `Somewhat describes me` parts dropping the rest.

I was trying to adapt the `str_match()` solution as presented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086448/6925293, but probably due to multiple special characters `{\"` etc, I can't make it work.

Comment: This is JSON content, and you should be using a JSON parser, _not_ regex.

Comment: True, this data comes from JSON. Didn't realize it makes a difference.
 Any idea how can I extract it?

Comment: How did you pull the data, within R or did you import as such into your R environment?

Comment: I used `stream_in()` from the `jsonlite` package

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for catching this. I edited my original question title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these are JSON strings, you can use the [jsonStrings](https://github.com/stla/jsonStrings) package:

```
library(jsonStrings)

x <- "{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}"
jstring <- jsonString$new(x)
jstring$at("label")
# "Describes me best"
```

Comment: How would you use jsonString() with a character vector. Do you need a loop/map, right? Something like:

1:length(txt) |> purrr::map(~{
    jstring <- jsonString$new(txt[.x])
    jstring$at("label")
  })

Comment: @Gorka Yes, or sapply/vapply

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```r
  txt <- c("{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}", "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", 
           "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", 
           "{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}", "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", 
           "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", "{\"label\":\"Describes me best\",\"multiplier\":1}", 
           "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}", "{\"label\":\"Somewhat describes me\",\"multiplier\":0.5}"
  )
  
  
# With gsub you can catch between () a pattern, and get it with \\1
  gsub(pattern = '.*"(.*)",.*', replacement = "\\1", x = txt)

#>  [1] "Describes me best"     "Somewhat describes me" "Somewhat describes me"
#>  [4] "Somewhat describes me" "Describes me best"     "Somewhat describes me"
#>  [7] "Somewhat describes me" "Describes me best"     "Somewhat describes me"
#> [10] "Somewhat describes me"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: While this solution does what I asked for, the `jsonStrings()` one gives me more flexibility and I'll accept that one. Still, thank you for the `gsub()` - I'll use it elsewhere.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the comment. I agree the jsonStrings is better when dealing with JSON strings. I tend to use gsub when the input is not always well formed JSON. Cheers.